# Join object string values that exist and in a custom order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am being passed an object containing address data (in alphabetical order) that I am wanting to extract a sub-set of to display, but in a different order.

Not all of the keys will have data in all of the time, sometimes having an empty string instead of nothing at all.

```
const address = {
  buildingName: '',
  company: 'My org',
  county: 'My County',
  postCode: 'My Postcode',
  streetName: 'My street',
  townCity: 'My Town'
};
```

I know that I can get all of the present values out by doing:

```
Object.keys(address).filter(Boolean).join(', ')
```

However I am wanting the order of the information being output to be: `company, buildingName, streetName, townCity, county, postCode`.

Is there any way in which I can alter my current solution, or do I need a different approach entirely?

Comment: like `your_keys.map(k=>address[k]).join()`?

Comment: You can construct object properties in that order manually. The output of `Object.keys(address)` will be in the expected order then.

Comment: @gog that achieves the same as I currently have but with no ordering :-/

Comment: @jkalandarov I forgot to mention (added to question now) that **I am being passed this data** in alphabetical order. I'm needing to get it into a different order myself.

Comment: `your_keys` is an array of keys defined in your code: `your_keys  = ['company', 'buildingName', etc`

Comment: `Object.keys.filter(Boolean)` will throw an error. Even if you change it to: `Object.keys(address).filter(Boolean)`, it will not work because it will filter the keys and not based on the values of the keys.

Comment: @gog you didn't make that clear at first! I did manage to get around the issue with something similar.

Comment: @gog I just tried your solution, but it doesn't account for any non-matching key entries, so the eventual string would have a bunch of empty bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `addressOrder` array, to specify the order of the various address components, then use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add to the output address components.

We'd only add the address to the output if it's present in the address object.

Finally we'd join the address components using the provided delimiter.

```js
const address = {
  buildingName: 'Nakatomi Towers',
  company: 'Nakatomi Corp.',
  county: 'LA County',
  postCode: '90067',
  streetName: 'Century City',
  townCity: 'LA'
};

function formatAddress(address, addressOrder, delimiter = ', ') { 
    return addressOrder.reduce((outputFields, field) => { 
        if (address[field]) {
            outputFields.push(address[field]);  
        }
        return outputFields;
    }, []).join(delimiter);
}

const order1 = ['company','buildingName','streetName','townCity','county','postCode']
const order2 = ['buildingName','streetName','townCity','postCode']

console.log('Address:', formatAddress(address, order1))
console.log('\nAddress (alt. format):\n' + formatAddress(address, order2, '\n'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need custom order you will have to create that object manually. You can use template array, but that is more or less the same solution.

```js
const address = {
    buildingName: '',
    company: 'My org',
    county: 'My County',
    postCode: 'My Postcode',
    streetName: 'My street',
    townCity: 'My Town'
};

const tmp = ["company", "buildingName", "streetName", "townCity", "county", "postCode"];
let s = "";
tmp.forEach(key => {
    const v = address[key];
    if(v) {
        if(s) s += ", ";
        s += v;
    }
});
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a solution combining Jan Pfeifer and Gog's solutions to some extent, along with my own experimentation.

It also transpired that fields with no value **weren't** being returned as empty strings, but weren't included, so that made things a bit easier.

```
const ADDRESS_ORDER = ['company', 'buildingName', 'streetName', 'townCity', 'county', 'postCode'];

return const addressString = ADDRESS_ORDER
    .filter(detail => Object.keys(address).includes(detail))
    .map(key => address[key])
    .join(', ');
```

```js
const ADDRESS_ORDER = ['company', 'buildingName', 'streetName', 'townCity', 'county', 'postCode'];

const address = {
  company: 'My org',
  county: 'My County',
  postCode: 'My Postcode',
  streetName: 'My street',
  townCity: 'My Town'
};

const result = ADDRESS_ORDER
    .filter(detail => Object.keys(address).includes(detail))
    .map(key => address[key])
    .join(', ');
    
console.log({result});
```

If this was any longer or more complex, I would consider tidying up by combining the `fileter` and `map` into a `reduce`, but I don't think it warrants this at the moment.